# mysql load data infile where clause

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I need to update existing rows in table with load data infile based on some condition, is this possible?

```
load data infile 'E:/xxx.csv'
into table tld_tod
@aaa, @xxx_date, @ccc
fields terminated by ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
set xxx = str_to_date(@xxx_date, '%d-%b-%y')
where xxx is not null and aaa=@aaa
```

Comment: Do it in two steps: first load the data in a temporary table then use it in an `UPDATE ... JOIN` query to update your target table.

Answer (score 4):

You ca also create a staging table, insert the data from the CSV file into the staging table and then finally insert the data into your target table with the required operations and filtering.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staging LIKE tld_tod;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:/xxx.csv'
INTO TABLE staging
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

INSERT INTO tld_tod
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(col_date, '%d-%b-%y') AS date
WHERE col_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL it's possible to create triggers before update. So in this case I suggest to use:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON table
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF NEW.xxx IS NOT NULL THEN
               SET NEW.xxx = 0;
           END IF;
       END;//
delimiter ;
```

After creating trigger, you can run load data infile without WHERE.
I'm not sure what's your specific required condition, but do it inside BEGIN and END.